# How to test a method for toHaveBeenCalled in unit testing an Error interceptor

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

What I'm trying to say is that I want to see if a particular method was called or not. I've an Error Interceptor. There are 3 methods (1 public and 2 private methods). Here is the code:

**interceptor**

```
import { ... } from '...';
...

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    switch (err.status) {
                        case 400:
                        case 403:
                            // some logic
                            break;
                        case 401:
                            return this.handle401Error(request, next); // This I've to check
                        default:
                            // some logic
                    }
                }
                const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
                return throwError(error);
            })
        );
    }

    private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) { // will be called in case: 401
        // some logic
    }

    private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) { // ignore this method
      // some logic
    }
}
```

Here is my spec file:

```
import { throwError, defer } from "rxjs";
import { ErrorInterceptor } from './error.interceptor';

describe('ErrorInterceptor', () => {
    let errorInterceptor;
    let authServiceSpy;

    beforeEach(() => {
        authServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthService', ['logout']);
        errorInterceptor = new ErrorInterceptor(authServiceSpy);
    })

    describe('intercept', () => {
        let httpRequestSpy;
        let httpHandlerSpy;
        const error = {status: 401, statusText: 'error'};

        it('should auto logout if 401 response returned from api', () => {
            //arrange
            httpRequestSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpRequest', ['doesNotMatter']);
            httpHandlerSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpHandler', ['handle']);
            httpHandlerSpy.handle.and.returnValue(throwError(
                {error: 
                    {message: 'test-error'}
                }
            ));
            //act
            errorInterceptor.intercept(httpRequestSpy, httpHandlerSpy)
                .subscribe(
                    result => console.log('good', result), 
                    err => { 
                        console.log('error', err);
                        expect(err).toEqual('test-error');
                        expect(errorInterceptor.handle401Error).toHaveBeenCalled();  //Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.
                    }
                );
        })
    })
})
```

When I check:

`expect(errorInterceptor.handle401Error).toHaveBeenCalled();`

I'm getting this error:

`Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.`

Please correct my mistake. Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53672234-hw9jb3).

Answer (score 1):

It's an access specifier mistake, since `handle401Error` is a private method, you cannot access directly by the reference like `errorInterceptor.handle401Error` from other pages. Check below ways;

**FirstWay**: So I do not prefer to assert `expect(errorInterceptor.handle401Error).toHaveBeenCalled();` instead I will include the private method's logic test cases in the parent method where it has been called.

**SecondWay**: You can get the psudo reference by initialising or spying on `errorInterceptor["handle401Error"]`

not sure of the syntax in Jasmine, but please refer the below code which I use in jest

```
// arrange
errorInterceptor["handle401Error"] = jest.fn();

// assert
expect(errorInterceptor["handle401Error"]).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry I didn't realize I'm calling a private method. I'm trying your method now.